# ASCII Animation Using System.Console.ANSI

Tags: haskell, animation, ascii-art

I'm on my third Haskell project for my class this semester and we went from hello world, to simple math, to animating ASCII characters using Haskell and I am completely dumbfounded for this project. My professor has nothing on his website about this, and the documentation for System.Console.ANSI is not very helpful. I can not find any examples about this online either after extensive searching.

Has anyone done this or at least tell me if I am going in the right direction?

The first question is this

---

[16] Use the System.Console.ANSI library to draw a frame-based color drawing [4]. It must be at least 8 rows by 16 columns [4] and have at least 2 frames [8], which should alternate infinitely. Call this color-comic.hs.

---

my color-comic.hs looks like this

```
module Main (
        main
    ) where

import System.Console.ANSI
import System.IO

import Control.Concurrent


colorComic :: [IO ()]
colorComic = [printBlock, flashBlue, flashRed]


main :: IO ()
main = do 
    colorComic

pause :: IO ()
pause = do
    hFlush stdout
    -- 1 second pause
    threadDelay 1000000


flashRed :: IO ()//change text color to red
flashRed = do 
    setSGR [SetColor Foreground Vivid Red]
    pause

flashBlue :: IO ()//change text color to blue
flashBlue = do
    setSGR [SetColor Foreground Vivid Blue]
    pause

printBlock :: IO ()// print 8x16 block
printBlock = do
    putStrLn "################"
    putStrLn "################"
    putStrLn "################"
    putStrLn "################"
    putStrLn "################"
    putStrLn "################"
    putStrLn "################"
    putStrLn "################"
```

I do not understand how to let this run infinitely, and I get this error and I am not sure why, `putStrLn` has always worked for me. Am I going about this correctly?

> color-comic.hs:39:5: parse error on input ‘putStrLn’

The second question is a lot tougher,  but I think I have an idea how to do this

---

[32] Use the System.Console.ANSI library to draw a colored animation in ASCII. The animation should be 25 rows x 60 cols [8], have a framerate of 30 Hz [4], last for no more than 10 seconds [4], use at least three colors [8], be such that no two consecutive frames in the animation are the same [8], and be unique [-32].

---

For the above question I could simply make a block of # in the correct dimensions, and then change the color of each row in succession and then redraw the whole block with the color pushed down one and a new color added and so on. I am not sure how to do Frame rate though.

Any help is deeply appreciated, I am just trying to learn.

Comment: If you are actually compiling the line `printBlock :: IO ()// print 8x16 block` (and others like it) then of course your code cannot parse - `//` is not Haskell comment syntax. [Here](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch10.html) is the Haskell syntax reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make the infinite flash by using recursion, which for some reason, wasn't causing it to hang before.

```
module Main (
        main
    ) where

import System.Console.ANSI
import System.IO

import Control.Concurrent


colorComic :: [IO ()]
colorComic = [printBlock]


main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ (\color_comic -> resetScreen >> color_comic) colorComic

resetScreen :: IO ()
resetScreen = clearScreen >> setSGR [Reset] >> setCursorPosition 0 0

pause :: IO ()
pause = do
    hFlush stdout
    -- 1 second pause
    threadDelay 1000000


printBlock :: IO ()
printBlock = do
    clearScreen >> setCursorPosition 0 0
    setSGR [SetColor Foreground Vivid Red]
    putStrLn "################"
    putStrLn "################"
    putStrLn "################"
    putStrLn "################"
    putStrLn "################"
    putStrLn "################"
    putStrLn "################"
    putStrLn "################"
    pause
    clearScreen >> setCursorPosition 0 0
    setSGR [SetColor Foreground Vivid Blue]
    putStrLn "################"
    putStrLn "################"
    putStrLn "################"
    putStrLn "################"
    putStrLn "################"
    putStrLn "################"
    putStrLn "################"
    putStrLn "################"
    pause
    printBlock
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the recursive call at the end of **printBlock** and the need for the **colorComic** function using iterateM_ instead of mapM_ in your **main** function.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  resetScreen
  iterateM_ (\_ -> printBlock) ()
```